# Determine whether the sequences converges uniformly on $(0, 1)$: $f_n(x) = x^{ 1/n}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I think it converges uniformly to $1$, but don't know how to pick an epsilon to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

- First, identify the *only possible limit* (which is the pointwise limit). Since, for every *fixed* $x_0\in(0,1)$, it holds that
  $$
  f_n(x_0)=x_0^{\frac{1}{n}} = e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln x_0}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e^0 =1
  $$
  we have that $(f_n)_n$ converges pointwise to the constant function $f=1$ on $(0,1)$.
- Now, let us prove it does **not** converge uniformly to $f$; the idea is that there should be a problem "around $0$" (since $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f_n(x) =0$ for every fixed $n$, but the limit $f$ clearly satisfies $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) =1$).

  Our goal is to find a sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $f_n(x_n) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \ell \neq 1$; this will imply the result, as then we will have
  $$
  \sup_{x\in(0,1)}\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert \geq \lvert f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)\rvert = \lvert f_n(x_n)-1\rvert\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \lvert\ell-1\rvert \neq 0.
  $$

  By the above, we expect that the problem is around $0$, so we want $x_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$. Let us "try" (after some trial and error) 
  $
  x_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{1}{e^n} \in(0,1)
  $ for all $n\geq 1$.
  Then
  $$
  f_n(x_n) = x_n^{1/n} = e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(e^{-n})} = e^{\frac{1}{n}\cdot (-n)} = \frac{1}{e} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{e} \neq 1
  $$
  and we are done.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question correctly...

Comment: @levap No problem. It would actually help if the OP had put the question in the body of the post, not only in the title...